# How to set the logic contract in proxy contract so that proxy contract can delegatecall to the logic contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, proxy-contracts, foundry, upgrading

i am making a upgradable contract, i am facing issue to set the proxy contract for implementation contract. I am usign openzeppelin-contracts-upgradable.
This is my deployscript :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
import "forge-std/Script.sol";
import "../src/Proxy.sol";
import "../src/Game.sol";     // THIS IS LOGIC CONTRACT

contract ProxyScript is Script {
    function run() external {
        uint256 privateKey = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");
        vm.startBroadcast(privateKey);
        Game game = new Game(); // Deploying the Game contract
       // May be i need to do something like this: Proxy proxy =new Proxy(address(game));
       // I know i have to deploy the proxy contract, but can't figure out how to fix it for 
       // logic contract so that proxy contract can delegate call to logic contract
        vm.stopBroadcast();
      
    }
}
```

This is my Proxy.sol:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/contracts/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";

contract Proxy is UUPSUpgradeable {
    constructor(address implementation) {
        // I set the constructor because i might need to deploy the proxy contract by 
        // passing the logic contract's address, like this: new Proxy(address(game))
    }


    function _authorizeUpgrade(
        address newImplementation
    ) internal virtual override {}
}
```

How can i fix the logic contract in proxy contract so that proxy contract can delegatecall to logic contract's function???

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inheriting from UUPSUpgradeable you will need to call it's constructor in your constructor since it requires [arguments](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors)

```
constructor(address implementation) UUPSUpgradeable(implementation, "") {
  // your custom constructor code here
}
```

See this solidity documentation for more info:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors

Then in your foundry script you can just deploy your Proxy as normal with something like:

```
Proxy p = new Proxy(address(game));
```

Note that if you want to have any kind of initialisation data you will need to update your constructor and pass it to the UUPSUpgradeable constructor.